# Complex sum function by grouping two variables within a dataframe in R

Tags: r

For the below Dataframe entry:

```
DF <- data.frame(Major=c("MATH","MATH","MATH","MLSP","MLSP","MLSP","BIOL","BIOL","BIOL","PSHY","PSHY","PSHY"), Age=(c(2,3,4,2,3,4,2,3,4,2,3,4)), 
                 MJR_1=c("BIOL","PSHY","AGBU","MATH","PSHY",0,"MLSP","MATH",0,0,"MATH","MLSP"), TRF_MJR_1=(c(7,2,2,3,2,0,3,2,0,0,2,2)),
                 MJR_2=c("PSHY","BIOL",0,"BIOL","MATH",0,"MATH","PSHY",0,0,"MLSP","BIOL"), TRF_MJR_2=(c(3,1,0,2,1,0,2,4,0,0,1,2)),
                 MJR_3=c(0,0,0,0,"BIOL",0,0,0,0,0,0,0), TRF_MJR_3=(c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)))
```

we get the following dataframe:

```
   Major  Age MJR_1 TRF_MJR_1 MJR_2 TRF_MJR_2 MJR_3 TRF_MJR_3
1   MATH   2  BIOL         7  PSHY         3     0         0
2   MATH   3  PSHY         2  BIOL         1     0         0
3   MATH   4  AGBU         2     0         0     0         0
4   MLSP   2  MATH         3  BIOL         2     0         0
5   MLSP   3  PSHY         2  MATH         1  BIOL         1
6   MLSP   4     0         0     0         0     0         0
7   BIOL   2  MLSP         3  MATH         2     0         0
8   BIOL   3  MATH         2  PSHY         4     0         0
9   BIOL   4     0         0     0         0     0         0
10  PSHY   2     0         0     0         0     0         0
11  PSHY   3  MATH         2  MLSP         1     0         0
12  PSHY   4  MLSP         2  BIOL         2     0         0
```

Well as, I need to have the below output table having a SUM function entitled “TRF_IN - Transferred IN” column major that adds the number of each transferred majors (TRF_MJR_1, TRF_MJR_2, etc...) in the appropriate grouping category of (Major and Age) in the first two columns; although the “Major” category change according to MJR_1, MJR_2, etc... as shown below.

I appreciate any help to avoid multiple “Merge” or “ddply” functions since the actual file is big and has many variables..

```
   Major Age TRF_IN_SUM
 1:  MATH   2          5
 2:  MATH   3          5
 3:  MATH   4          0
 4:  MLSP   2          3
 5:  MLSP   3          1
 6:  MLSP   4          2
 7:  BIOL   2          9
 8:  BIOL   3          2
 9:  BIOL   4          2
10:  PSHY   2          3
11:  PSHY   3          8
12:  PSHY   4          0    
**13:  AGBU   4          2**
```

Explanation of output table:

```
Row1: Math major with Age 2:  
TRF_IN = "3" from TRF_MJR_1 in Row(4) having MJR_1= Math and Age =2 
+ 
TRF_IN = "2" from  TRF_MJR_2 in Row(7) having MJR_2= Math and Age =2

Row2: Math major with Age 3 :  
TRF_IN = "1" from TRF_MJR_2 in Row(5) having MJR_2= Math and Age =3 
+ 
TRF_IN = "2" from  TRF_MJR_1 in Row(8) having MJR_1= Math and Age =3
+
TRF_IN = "2" from  TRF_MJR_1 in Row(11) having MJR_1= Math and Age =3
```

Comment: I don't understand which variable you want to sum and group by what. Can you be more explicit please ?

Comment: Not clear to me either

Comment: Maybe you could explain in your post how to get to the first two lines of your desired output?

Comment: Row1: Math major with Age 2:  
TRF_IN = "3" from TRF_MJR_1 in Row(4) having MJR_1= Math and Age =2 
+ 
TRF_IN = "2" from  TRF_MJR_2 in Row(7) having MJR_2= Math and Age =2

Comment: Row2: Math major with Age 3 : TRF_IN = "1" from TRF_MJR_2 in Row(5) having MJR_2= Math and Age =3 
+ 
TRF_IN = "2" from  TRF_MJR_1 in Row(8) having MJR_1= Math and Age =3
+
TRF_IN = "2" from  TRF_MJR_1 in Row(11) having MJR_1= Math and Age =3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `melt()` function from the `data.table` package can reshape multiple measure columns simultaneously which is required here.

#### Variant 1:

```
library(data.table)
# reshape from wide to long format
melt(setDT(DF), id.vars = c("Major", "Age"), 
     measure.vars = patterns("^MJR_", "^TRF_MJR_"))[
       # omit null entries
       value1 != "0" & value2 != 0L][
         # aggregate
         , .(TRF_IN_SUM = sum(value2)), 
         keyby = .(Major = value1, Age)][
           # right join with first two columns of wide data set
           DF[, 1:2], on = c("Major", "Age")][
             # replace NA by 0
             is.na(TRF_IN_SUM), TRF_IN_SUM := 0L][]
```

> ```
>     Major Age TRF_IN_SUM
>  1:  MATH   2          5
>  2:  MATH   3          5
>  3:  MATH   4          0
>  4:  MLSP   2          3
>  5:  MLSP   3          1
>  6:  MLSP   4          2
>  7:  BIOL   2          9
>  8:  BIOL   3          2
>  9:  BIOL   4          2
> 10:  PSHY   2          3
> 11:  PSHY   3          8
> 12:  PSHY   4          0
> ```

**Edit 1:** By right joining with the first two columns of the original (wide) data, the result has the same number and order of rows. `NA` indicating missing data are replaced by 0.

**Caveat:** As pointed out by the OP, any value in the `MJR`which is not already included in the `Major`column won't appear in the result, e.g., `AGBU`. So this is not recommended.

#### Variant 2:

This is using `melt()` as before but follows [Frank's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45793742/complex-sum-function-by-grouping-two-variables-within-a-dataframe-in-r#comment78559912_45795751) using `CJ()` but enhances this by using factors to maintain the given order of the  `Major` column and "prettifies" the result. Note, that the handy `forcats` package is used.

```
library(data.table)
library(forcats)
setDT(DF)[
  # make sure factor levels are in order of occurence
  , Major := fct_inorder(Major)][
    # reshape wide to long with multiple measures columns 
    , melt(.SD, measure.vars = patterns("^MJR", "^TRF"), 
           value.name = c("MJR", "TRF"))][
             # omit null entries
             MJR != "0"][
               # unify factor levels with levels of Major in lead
               , c("Major", "MJR") := fct_unify(.(Major, factor(MJR)))][
                 # use cross join to create all combinations of MJR and Age,
                 # right join with results 
                 CJ(MJR, Age, unique = TRUE), on = .(MJR = V1, Age = V2), 
                 # aggregate by join parameters
                 .(TRF_IN_SUM = sum(TRF, na.rm = TRUE)), by = .EACHI]
```

> ```
>      MJR Age TRF_IN_SUM
>  1: MATH   2          5
>  2: MATH   3          5
>  3: MATH   4          0
>  4: MLSP   2          3
>  5: MLSP   3          1
>  6: MLSP   4          2
>  7: BIOL   2          9
>  8: BIOL   3          2
>  9: BIOL   4          2
> 10: PSHY   2          3
> 11: PSHY   3          8
> 12: PSHY   4          0
> 13: AGBU   2          0
> 14: AGBU   3          0
> 15: AGBU   4          0
> ```

Now, the result includes `AGBU` while showing all `MJR` and `Age` combinations and preserving the original order in `Major`.

However, this still might not be perfect in case there is an entry in `Major` which doesn't appear in any of the `MJR` columns. To cover this case, a full join, i.e., `merge()` with `all = TRUE` would suit better.

Comment: Thanks it works but I still need to show all rows even if data is not available e.g MATH for age 4 should be shown with "TRF_IN_SUM" = 0 same as with PSHY with age 4. Is there a way to provide with an output file having the two first column data as before and adding only "TRF_IN_SUM"

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Hope, the polished code is what you are after.

Comment: it works but I still hope to get also the transferred data that had no grouping category in the first two columns; E.g. refer to the changes made in data input where in row(3); MJR_1 =AGBU with Age=4; to be reflected in the output file at the end; is it possible to have left join in that case ? In another word, all transferred data should be reflected in the output file even if there is no group matching !

Comment: Alternately, `melt(setDT(DF), meas = patterns("^TRF", "^MJR"), value.name = c("TRF", "MJR"))[CJ(MJR = MJR, Age = Age, unique=TRUE), on=.(MJR, Age), sum(TRF, na.rm=TRUE), by=.EACHI]` @jean

Comment: This is the output that I got but I don't need the first 5 rows !!!!!!!!     MJR   Age V1
 1:    0   2  0
 2:    0   3  0
 3:    0   4  0
 4: AGBU   2  0
 5: AGBU   3  0
 6: AGBU   4  2
 7: BIOL   2  9
 8: BIOL   3  2
 9: BIOL   4  2
10: MATH   2  5
11: MATH   3  5
12: MATH   4  0
13: MLSP   2  3
14: MLSP   3  1
15: MLSP   4  2
16: PSHY   2  3
17: PSHY   3  8
18: PSHY   4  0

Comment: I've picked up @Frank 's approach and modified it to remove the zeros and to maintain the original order of `Major`.